# struggling to define and set required sheets correctly

Tags: excel, vba

If I open my workbook fresh and run the code, this works totally fine. However, further down the process I open a second workbook (**SourceWorkbook**), run through the whole process, and then try to run it again, I run into problems.

The process starts with pressing a button on the "Settings" sheet to run. To start with I want to check that various settings are filled in correctly, first finding the settings labels to find the coordinates of the settings.

```
Function ImportClientData()

          Dim myRng As Range
          
10        TargetWorkbookStr = ActiveWorkbook.Name
20        Set TargetWorkbook = Workbooks(TargetWorkbookStr)
          
          'Check that all the settings are present and correct
30        Call CheckSettings

40        If proceed = False Then Exit Function


          'Import the client data sheet
          'Assume clear all existing data and start again

50        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
60        CurrentURL = ActiveWorkbook.Path
70        Application.StatusBar = "Clearing 'Report' sheets"

80        Set ReportSheet = TargetWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
          '.ReportSheet.Activate

90        With ReportSheet
100           For RowCount = 1 To 10
110               If .Cells(RowCount, 1) = "OT initials" Then
120                   RowStartReport = RowCount + 1
130                   ColStartReport = 1
140                   RowLastReport = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
150                   ColLastReport = .Cells(RowCount, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

160               End If
170           Next RowCount

              'Clear content of 'Report'
180           ReportSheet.Select

190           .Range(.Cells(RowStartReport, ColStartReport), .Cells(RowLastReport, ColLastReport)).Select
              'Range(Cells(RowStartReport, ColStartReport), Cells(RowLastReport, ColLastReport)).ClearContents
              'Range(Cells(RowStartReport, ColStartReport), Cells(RowLastReport, ColLastReport)).ClearFormats

              'Import data for new Report
200       End With

          
210       Application.StatusBar = "Getting file to import"

220       Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

230       With fd
          
240           .Filters.Clear
250           .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*", 1
260           .Title = "Select the client details report"
270           .AllowMultiSelect = False
280           .InitialFileName = CurrentURL

290           If .Show = True Then

300               SourceToOpen = .SelectedItems(1)
                  
310               Set SourceWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(SourceToOpen)
320               Set SourceWorksheet = ActiveSheet
330               SourceWorkbookStr = ActiveSheet.Name
340               Debug.Print SourceWorkbookStr

350               RowStartSource = 2
360               RowLastSource = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
370               ColStartSource = 1
380               ColLastSource = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

                  'Loop through each row to check if the record realtes to a required client (based on client group)
                  'and then extract the relevant data
                  'Identify the columns to filter the records by
390               For ColCountSource = ColStartSource To ColLastSource
                      
400                   If Cells(1, ColCountSource) = "Client group" Then ClientGroupCol = ColCountSource
                      'Will need date closed
410               Next ColCountSource
                  
420               Call GetColumnNumbers

430               For RowCountSource = RowStartSource To RowLastSource
440                   If IsInArray(Cells(RowCountSource, ClientGroupCol), ClientGroupArray) Then
                          'Extract Information from this record
                          
450                       Debug.Print "Include - " & Cells(RowCountSource, ClientGroupCol)
460                   Else
                          'Skip this record
470                   End If
480               Next RowCountSource
490           End If
500       End With
          
End Function
```

```
Function CheckSettings()

          '#######################################################################
          '# This checks that all the setting on the Settings page are filled in #
          '#######################################################################

          Dim FoundRange As Range
          Dim TitleNotFoundStr As String
          Dim DataMissingStr As String
          Dim DataSummaryStr As String
          
          Dim ArrayStr As String
          Dim PreviousClientGroup As Boolean  'The previous client group had a value
          
          Dim LabelList(6) As String
          Dim k As Integer


10        FirstRow = 1
20        LastRow = 100
30        FirstCol = 1
40        LastCol = 20

50        TitleNotFoundStr = ""
60        DataMissingStr = ""
70        DataSummaryStr = ""
80        ArrayStr = ""
90        proceed = False
100       ClientGroupCount = 0
110       PreviousClientGroup = False
          
120       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
130       Set TargetWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

140       Set SettingsWorksheet = TargetWorkbook.Worksheets("Settings")

150       With SettingsWorksheet
160           LabelList(0) = CMNameLabel
170           LabelList(1) = CMInitialLabel
180           LabelList(2) = ClientGroupLabel
190           LabelList(3) = OpenCasesLabel
200           LabelList(4) = ClosedCasesLabel
210           LabelList(5) = DateClosedLabel

              'Loops through the array of required labels to check if the labels are all present and correct, and
              'have the required information filled in.

220           For k = 0 To 5
230               SettingsWorksheet.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(100, 20)).Select
240               Set FoundRange = SettingsWorksheet.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(100, 20)).Find(LabelList(k))
250               If FoundRange Is Nothing Then
260                   If TitleNotFoundStr = "" Then
270                       TitleNotFoundStr = "The following setting labels have not been found in settings:" & vbCr & vbCr & _
                              LabelList(k)
280                   Else
290                       TitleNotFoundStr = TitleNotFoundStr & vbCr & LabelList(k)
300                   End If
310               Else
320                   If LabelList(k) = CMNameLabel Then
330                       CMName = Cells(Range(FoundRange.Address).Row, Range(FoundRange.Address).Column + 2)
340                       DataSummaryStr = DataSummaryStr & vbCr & CMNameLabel & ": " & vbTab & CMName
350                   End If
360                   If LabelList(k) = CMInitialLabel Then
370                       CMInitials = Cells(Range(FoundRange.Address).Row, Range(FoundRange.Address).Column + 2)
380                       DataSummaryStr = DataSummaryStr & vbCr & CMInitialLabel & ": " & vbTab & CMInitials
390                   End If
400                   If LabelList(k) = ClientGroupLabel Then
410                       ClientGroupFirstRow = Range(FoundRange.Address).Row
420                       ClientGroupLastRow = Range(FoundRange.Address).Row + NoClientGroups - 1
430                       For RowCount = ClientGroupFirstRow To ClientGroupLastRow
440                           myStr = Cells(RowCount, Range(FoundRange.Address).Column + 2)
450                           If myStr = "" Then
460                               If PreviousClientGroup = False And Cells(RowCount, Range(FoundRange.Address).Column + 1) = 1 Then
470                                   myCheck = MsgBox("Qunote Client Groups must be filled in in numerical order e.g. " & vbCr & _
                                          "Number 1 only if there 1 client group," & vbCr & _
                                          "Numbers 1 and 2 if there are 2 client groups, etc" & vbCr & vbCr & _
                                          "Please correct this", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Correct client groups")
480                                   Exit Function
490                               End If
500                               PreviousClientGroup = False
510                           Else
520                               If PreviousClientGroup = False And Cells(RowCount, Range(FoundRange.Address).Column + 1) <> 1 Then
530                                   myCheck = MsgBox("Qunote Client Groups must be filled in in numerical order e.g. " & vbCr & _
                                          "Number 1 only if there 1 client group," & vbCr & _
                                          "Numbers 1 and 2 if there are 2 client groups, etc" & vbCr & vbCr & _
                                          "Please correct this.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Correct client groups")
540                                   Exit Function
550                               Else
560                                   If Cells(RowCount, Range(FoundRange.Address).Column + 1) = 1 Then
570                                       DataSummaryStr = DataSummaryStr & vbCr & ClientGroupLabel & ": " & vbTab & myStr
580                                       ArrayStr = myStr
590                                   Else
600                                       DataSummaryStr = DataSummaryStr & vbCr & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & myStr
610                                       ArrayStr = ArrayStr & "," & myStr
620                                   End If
630                               End If
640                               ClientGroupCount = ClientGroupCount + 1
650                               PreviousClientGroup = True

660                           End If
                              
670                       Next RowCount
680                       ClientGroupArray = Split(ArrayStr, ",")
690                   End If
700                   If LabelList(k) = OpenCasesLabel Then
710                       SelectOpenCases = Cells(Range(FoundRange.Address).Row, Range(FoundRange.Address).Column + 2)
720                       DataSummaryStr = DataSummaryStr & vbCr & OpenCasesLabel & ": " & vbTab & vbTab & SelectOpenCases
730                   End If
740                   If LabelList(k) = ClosedCasesLabel Then
750                       SelectClosedCases = Cells(Range(FoundRange.Address).Row, Range(FoundRange.Address).Column + 2)
760                       DataSummaryStr = DataSummaryStr & vbCr & ClosedCasesLabel & ": " & vbTab & vbTab & SelectClosedCases
                      
770                   End If
780                   If LabelList(k) = DateClosedLabel Then
790                       DateClosed = Cells(Range(FoundRange.Address).Row, Range(FoundRange.Address).Column + 2)
800                       DataSummaryStr = DataSummaryStr & vbCr & DateClosedLabel & ": " & vbTab & DateClosed
810                   End If
820               End If
830           Next k

840           If CMName = "" Then DataMissingStr = DataMissingStr & vbCr & CMNameLabel
850           If CMInitials = "" Then DataMissingStr = DataMissingStr & vbCr & CMInitialLabel
860           If SelectOpenCases = "" Then DataMissingStr = DataMissingStr & vbCr & OpenCasesLabel
870           If SelectClosedCases = "" Then DataMissingStr = DataMissingStr & vbCr & ClosedCasesLabel
880           If DateClosed = 0 Then DataMissingStr = DataMissingStr & vbCr & DateClosedLabel
              
              
890           If TitleNotFoundStr <> "" Then
900               myCheck = MsgBox(TitleNotFoundStr & vbCr & vbCr & "Please make sure the labels on the Settings page are correct " & _
                      "and include the above.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Labels missing")
910               proceed = False
920           Else
930               If DataMissingStr <> "" Then
940                   myCheck = MsgBox("The following information is missing from the 'Settings' sheet:" & vbCr & vbCr & DataMissingStr & vbCr & vbCr & _
                          "Please fill in all the required information.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Information missing")
950                   proceed = False
960               Else
970                   If DataSummaryStr <> "" Then
980                       myCheck = MsgBox("Is the following information correct?" & vbCr & DataSummaryStr & vbCr & vbCr & _
                              "If not, press no and correct the information in Settings.", vbInformation + vbYesNo, "Settings summary")
990                       If myCheck = vbYes Then
1000                          proceed = True
1010                      Else
1020                          proceed = False
1030                      End If
1040                  End If
1050              End If

1060          End If


1070      End With


End Function
```

On the first run through I get the summary message box stating that everything has been found (line 980 of **CheckSettings**. However, if I then try again I get the message box telling me that the labels can't be found (line 900).

I put in the line `SettingsWorksheet.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(100, 20)).Select` on line 230 to check if I was looking in the right place, and the cells that are selected are in the required sheet ("Settings")

It is clearly not looking where I think it is looking, but why??

Comment: You need to qualify all `Cells(..)` and `Range(..)` in your code, otherwise it will be equalient to `ActiveSheet.Cells(..)` and `ActiveSheet.Range(..)`. ActiveSheet is changed after the 2nd workbook is opened. Please always use fully qualified reference, eg. `SettingsWorksheet.Range()`.

Comment: I have used a fully qualified reference, haven't I? I set SettingsWorksheet in line 140 and then 'Set FoundRange = SettingsWorksheet.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(100, 20)).Find(LabelList(k))' in line 240.

Comment: `Option Explicit` would help here.

Comment: The line numbers are a blast from the past but using them on some lines but not others is definitely something I have never seen before, it is difficult to predict what effect that will have. Line numbers are not required nowadays, use labels if you need to. The error message *labels can't be found (line 900)* - is that the actual error message or have you summarised what VBA says?

Comment: For line 140, yes. But you do have many lines like this `CMName = Cells(Range(FoundRange.Address).Row, Range(FoundRange.Address).Column + 2)`.

Comment: @user10186832 I do have Option Explicit at the top of each module. The line numbers come from a VBA add-on (MZ-Tools) I use, I only added them in for reference in this query, I get the same results with or without them. Sorry, that is not an actual error message, that is me summarising the outcome. The code itself doesn't throw any errors (at least not at the point I'm referring to here), but it doesn't do what I'm expecting either.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Some of the labels have a ":" in them, so the values didn't match exactly.

However, that raises the question why they were found OK on the first run through. I assume it is because later in the process I used `.Find` but I specify `LookAt:=1`.

Instead I changed the code to this, is works perfectly every time:

```
Set FoundRange = SettingsWorksheet.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(100, 20)).Find(What:=LabelList(k), LookAt:=2)
```

Comment: Well done, thanks for posting the answer. Take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!

Comment: You probably have done this already but just in case here is how to Turn on option explicit by default for all VBA Code modules  ...  Developer > Visual Basic > Insert > Module > Tools > Options > Require variable declaration > Tick the box > OK